# Conditional Statement In Header to add Canonical tag

Tags: php, html, header, canonical-link

Hi I need to find a way to add a conditional statement that will insert a canonical tag depending on the pages URL

The canonical tag itself is fine and I presume it would be something around it like you would do with css. I know PHP can get the details of the pages URL.

```
<!--IF HEADER URL = "PAGE URL HERE" -->
    <link rel="canonical" href="LINK HERE" />
<!--IF HEADER URL-->
```

This leads me to the second issue I am having.
The pages I am wanting to add a canonical tag too don't always have the same link

- embassy_details.php?embassy=Afghanistan
- embassy_details.php?embassy=Africa
- embassy_details.php?embassy=America

what I was thinking is to put the initial conditional statement around it and then put it on all the pages which link contains (embassy_details.php) as this is what I need on it

If you need more clarity just message me.

inb4 Creating a new header file for this page is out of the question due to the previous developers methods.

---

EDIT

I have nearly achieved the above goal with JQuery i am jsut having problems appending. I can alert the tag but i think there is something wrong with my append statement.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var l = window.location.href;

        if (l.indexOf("embassy_details.php") > -1) {
            $('head').append('<link rel="canonical" href="http://LINK/embassies.php" />');
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean

```
if (isset($_GET['embassy'])) {
        $embassy = $_GET['embassy'];
        echo '<link rel="canonical" href="embassy_details.php?embassy='.$embassy.'" />';
    } else {
        $embassy = '';
        echo '<link rel="canonical" href="embassy_details.php" />';
    }
```

doesn't match for you?

Comment: Updated the question near with a JQuery olution

Comment: why js? why jQuery? it is standard situation, and standard solution to place data while php generate the page. Why do you need to change canonical tag after page is output to the client? what is the use case when this is necessary ?

Comment: and by the way this tag is useful for SEO, but if you change it dynamically from jQuery it has no sense at all.

Comment: when i use php methods the pae jsut seems to crumble, correctly using the `<?php ?>` tag but it prints `});` at the top of the page. i have also ensured that all the lines are correctly ended with `;`

Comment: its any php within a <?php ?> it prints the end off

Comment: "any of php code" is mine sample - it works fine, so could you show us your code please to help you?

Comment: <?php

 if (isset($_GET['embassy_details.php'])) {
        $embassy = $_GET['embassy'];
        echo '<link rel="canonical" href="embassy_details.php?embassy='.$embassy.'" />';
    } else {
        $embassy = '';
        echo '<link rel="canonical" href="embassy_details.php" />';
    }

 ?>

Comment: that print on the page as `'; } else { $embassy = ''; echo ''; } ?>`

Comment: so try to remove <?php at first line and ?> at the end

Comment: then it is in the plain html surrounded by other html elements

Comment: when i look at it in f12 it appears to be adding comment arround it

Comment: did you copied my code? or did you retyped it by yourself ?

Comment: dude, the php approach isn't working for me. even if i type `<?php echo "test"; ?>` it prints `"; ?>` is there another approach to this?

Comment: it isn't it is being used all over the site efficiently.

Comment: you wrote : "even if i type <?php echo "test"; ?> it prints "; ?> " - is it efficient proper php service working fine?

Comment: all the php services and things are running smoothly

Comment: do you have a link to your page?

Comment: Sorry I am not allowed to disclose the page when referring to source, company Policy. As it is a development iste it is in house too

Comment: the only guess I have - that you have some unclosed double qoutes on the page or unclosed tags <? ?> , try to remove everithing from the page - leave just this piece of code - my code is working fine - so once you get it work - just add all the rest (html + php) piece by piece to the page - to find whitch part is broken. good luck

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have been working on it this morning, fresh mind because had a good sleep. The solution that worked for me was to do in in the `body.php`. I choose to add my statement here because of all the issues i was having with the header. What my code does is checks if the link contains embassy_details.php and then adds it to the very beginning of the header.

```
<?php

$link = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

if (strpos($link,'embassy_details.php') !== false) {
    echo str_replace('</head>', '', '<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.LINK.co.uk/embassies.php")');
}

?>
```

This appends it into the header for all the Embassy details ages correctly